How do you scale the middle of a mesh using Geometry Nodes?
I want to create a series of customizable objects. I am stuck on trying to scale the middle part of a mesh without impacting the edges. Take this mesh, for example:

How would I adjust the X axis of the highlighted part of the mesh only? I tried searching online, but ran up empty. I've also tried building out graphs with the index and position nodes but ran into a wall.
Thanks!

I can't write an answer now, but basically : create vertex group for the center -> use it in geometry nodes (same as an attribute) -> plug it as selection for transform.

That's helpful - my problem at this point is that when I try to select the vertex group in the modifier attribute it's not listed there. I did create one on the original geometry though. Based on the videos I've found online - people leave the Type of the input attribute to Boolean. Any idea what may be the issue with it not showing up?

Got it! That was incredibly helpful. Thank you :) I'll mark your answer as correct once you have a moment to post it.

Do you just want to scale the faces, or bring the ends inwards, too?

For anyone who runs into this.

Select your vertices and create a Vertex Group.



Add a Named Attribute node and set the name to your Vertex Group. Hook it up to the Selection input for a Set Position node.

You can see my full graph here -

In my example I have a Trailer Size float property that can be set in the Modifier tab - this drives the overall size.
